# c# Dynamic Where clause in a lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, where-clause

I have a page that allow the user to search by multiple fields. One can be used or all. The user can set the operator per field to Equals, Contains, Starts With, etc... Looks like this [image]

I am using EntityFrame Work and retrieving the data using a lamba like this one:

```
listOfPeople = adDB.People.Where(x => x.LastName.StartsWith(lastName) && x.FirstName.StartsWith(firstName)).OrderBy(x => x.LastName)
```

The question, How do I dynamically create the where clause depending on the data provided by the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# LINQ Dynamic Select with all type of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789229/c-sharp-linq-dynamic-select-with-all-type-of-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something along the lines of a Func factory to do this since the where clause takes in a Func.

Example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var people = new[]
        {   
            new Person {FirstName = "Hello", LastName = "World"}, 
            new Person {FirstName = "Foo", LastName = "Bar"},
        };

        Console.WriteLine(people.Where(FuncFactory.GetFilterFunc<Person>(FilterType.Contains, x => x.FirstName, "ello")).Any());
        Console.WriteLine(people.Where(FuncFactory.GetFilterFunc<Person>(FilterType.Equals, x => x.FirstName, "ello")).Any());
        Console.WriteLine(people.Where(FuncFactory.GetFilterFunc<Person>(FilterType.Contains, x => x.LastName, "ar")).Any());
        Console.WriteLine(people.Where(FuncFactory.GetFilterFunc<Person>(FilterType.Equals, x => x.LastName, "ar")).Any());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public enum FilterType
{
    Contains,
    Equals
}

public static class FuncFactory
{
    public static Func<T, bool> GetFilterFunc<T>(FilterType filterType, Func<T, IComparable> propFunc, string filter)
    {
        switch (filterType)
        {
            case FilterType.Contains:
                return x => (propFunc(x) as string).Contains(filter);
            case FilterType.Equals:
                return x => (propFunc(x) as string).Equals(filter);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid FilterType");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Predicate Builder:

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx