# Entity Framework building Where clause on the fly using Expression

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio, predicate

Using Entity Framework C# and have this query, I need the part where it says:

```
where x.Login_Status == "Submitted"
```

to be dynamic. There are different cases it could be "Submitted" or null or something else and instead of writing multiple if statement with different queries in it, want to have a Predicate in a where clause.

```
status = (from x in ctx.table
          where x.Login_Status == "Submitted"
          orderby x.SUB_DATE descending
          select new Model_Table()
          {
              Id = x.ID,
              Name = x.NAME,
              Code = x.Code,
              DateSubmitted = x.SUB_DATE
           }).ToList<Model_Table>();
```

Is that possible?

**Solution:**

Inside the if statement when more parameters encountered use this

```
where_expression = x => x.Login_Status == "Submitted" || x.Login_Status == null;
```

Here is a complete code that worked for me, anything between square brackets replace to suit your code:

```
Expression<Func<[Replace with your Entity], bool>> where_submitted = x => x.Login_Status == "Submitted";

// Check if all selected
if (CheckBox_Show_All_Submitted.Checked)
{
    where_submitted = x => x.Login_Status == "Submitted" || x.Login_Status == null;
}

status = 
    ctx.[Replace with your Entity Table]
    .Where(where_submitted)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.SUB_DATE)
    .Select(x => new Model_Table
        {
           Id = x.ID,
           Name = x.NAME,
           Code = x.Code,
           DateSubmitted = x.SUB_DATE
        }).ToList<Model_Table>();
```

Comment: You could use a bitwise enum, and use [Enum.HasFlag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (that doesn't account for the null case, really).

Comment: See my answer in a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34098534/1677829

Comment: You need an expression, not a predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `Expression<Func<Entity,bool>>`, not a `Predicate<Entity>`. The difference is that a predicate is a compiled delegate, and an expression is code as data and thus can be translated to SQL.

Here is an example:

```
//You can have this expression have different values based on your logic
Expression<Func<Entity,bool>> where_expression = x => x.Login_Status == "Submitted";

var query =
    ctx.Table
    .Where(where_expression)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.SUB_DATE)
    .Select(x => new Model_Table())
    {
        Id = x.ID,
        Name = x.NAME,
        Code = x.Code,
        DateSubmitted = x.SUB_DATE
   }).ToList();
```

Please note that you need to replace `Entity` with the name of the real class.

Comment: This really helps. There is a slight issue. When using this expression Expression<Func<Entity,bool>> where_expression = x => x.Login_Status == "Submitted"; it only applies to values "Submitted" but I need to have both "Submitted" and null.

Comment: You can have whatever condition in the expression. E.g. you can have `x => x.Login_Status == "Submitted" || x.Login_Status == null`.

Answer (score -1):

Create an extension method for IQueryable like this:

```
public static class MethodExtensions{

      public static IEnumerable<Model_Table> Query(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string data){
             return (from x in source
             where x.Login_Status == data
             orderby x.SUB_DATE descending
             select new Model_Table()
            {
                Id = x.ID,
                Name = x.NAME,
                Code = x.Code,
                DateSubmitted = x.SUB_DATE
            }).ToList<Model_Table>();
      }
}
```

---

Now you can use it like this:

```
var result = ctx.table.Query("somethingelse");
```

Comment: OP is using entity framework so `ctx.table` is of type `IQueryable<YourType>`.

Comment: If is using ef the tables are DbSet<TEntity> wich implements IEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>...

Comment: Right. But if you use `IEnumerable<TEntity>`, then all of the table content will be queried and stored in memory, and the `Where` and `OrderBy` will be executed in memory. What I mean to say is that your extension method should accept `IQueryable<YourType>` so that the querying will happen at the database side, not in memory.